# In Android Transitions how to stop background from showing briefly

Tags: android-transitions

I try to learn some Android [Transitions](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/transitions.html) but I cannot understand how to stop the background from showing in between the `Scenes`. This all happens in a `Fragment` and the parent `Activity` show between the `Scenes`.

How can I fix this?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_transition);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                   .add(R.id.container, new TransitionFragment())
                                   .commit();
    }
    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mScene1 = Scene.getSceneForLayout(container, R.layout.fragment_transition_scene_1, this);
    mScene2 = Scene.getSceneForLayout(container, R.layout.fragment_transition_scene_2, this);
    mTransitionManager = new TransitionManager();
    TransitionSet transitionSet = new TransitionSet();
    transitionSet.setOrdering(TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER);
    transitionSet.addTransition(new Fade()).addTransition(new ChangeBounds());
    mTransitionManager.setTransition(mScene1, mScene2, transitionSet);

}

public void goToScene1(View view) {
    mTransitionManager.transitionTo(mScene1);
}

public void goToScene2(View view) {
    mTransitionManager.transitionTo(mScene2);
}
```

Comment: Let me know whether applying [`Window#setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(boolean)) helps.

Comment: Thanks, I put a background color on the container did the trick